# Using the Google Cloud Platform for deploying React applications

Tags: reactjs, git, deployment, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app

I have a basic React application generated using: `create-react-app`.

My source code is hosted on GitHub.

I wish to use the Google Cloud Platform to host my React application.

(I also have a custom domain).

Every time a push/ merge/ code change is made on the `master` branch, I wanted the hosted application on GCP to update my website contents from `master`.

Previously I have been unsuccessful in following the instructions provided by Google in setting up a continuous integration process for updating & deploying my application.

I used the Google Cloud Build GitHub app in attempt to update & build my application but with no success.

My `cloudbuild.yaml` file consisting of:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['build']
```

I also had a bucket set up with a working `appspot.com` URL (having cloned & deployed the application using the built in console on the GCP website) - which was mapped to my custom domain.

My attempts at updating this deployed version failed miserably.

In frustration of trying to achieve my desired workflow, I switched to Netlify which allowed me to achieve what I wanted, and deleted my project from GCP.

**I am now attempting to start another project from scratch** (on GCP) and needed some assistance in making sure I set up this new project correctly, a step by step guide if you will. I'm a complete novice when it comes to production level deployment of applications, having only practised with and developed 'dev' level applications on my own machine and I haven't found anywhere else that will help me achieve what I would like to do.

The workflow I am trying to achieve is as follows:

- I make changes to my code on the master branch
- Changes get pushed to GitHub/ the master branch
- Changes get pulled from GitHub into GCP and the website gets updated
- I can see the changes when I visit my custom domain

How can I achieve this properly? Or is GCP not the ideal solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories

Found what you are looking for!

This will make it so every time you commit, google app engine automatically redeploys.

*Edit*

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

In your `package.json`, add `"build:gcp": "react-scripts build && node server.js",` to it.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:gcp": "react-scripts build && node server.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

Now when you deploy your app, run the `npm run build:gcp` command and you will know for sure your app is running in production mode.

Comment: How do I ensure the React application is 'built' (minified into production files) before deploying? What do I need to do in order to achieve this? - that's what I was trying to get at. I've seen this link already, I'm just missing the bit in-between

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Instead of running `npm start`, run `npm run build` and have your server file serve the files in the build folder. I posted a example of a `server.js` that you can use

Comment: It's been a full working week since the original question, I've been at work doing other things so I've pretty much forgotten how I got to the stage I did last time. For the sake of someone else trying to find a way to do this, would you mind putting together a step by step guide as to what to do first, for someone with a custom domain too? Maybe I misunderstood the instructions on the google cloud website but my bucket is still empty even after deploying my app using the command line `gcloud deploy`  (as instructed in your comment link above^). Is this correct?

Comment: And I think I may have done something incorrectly after deploying because my appspot domain does not want to take me to my application page at all

Comment: Have you looked at the logs? Thats really strange how it just stopped working

Comment: Sadly I gave up and used firebase hosting instead.

Comment: No need to be sorry! I found another issue which I wonder if you could perhaps have a look at, if you're familiar with `yml` configs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909145/yml-config-for-building-deploying-react-app

Comment: I will take a look in a hour or so